# What are the Cycles specific Viewport Display settings in the material tab good for?

Tags: materials, 3d-view, interface, properties

The material tab contains a Viewport display panel. Here you can set the color to display a mesh in green in solid mode for example.

But there is also a Setting sub panel. And its content does simply nothing in the viewport.

Is this panel for Cycles in the wrong place? Because with Eevee these settings are in the Settings tab.

[image]

Comment: Wow! I had no idea these settings are accesible through the properties panel, this is great :). I always switched to Eevee to adjust them.

Comment: @JachymMichal Same here... I think the location of these settings is unfortunate...

Comment: Moreover, you can't access it under the viewport display settings if you're accessing it from the shader editor in the N-Panel...

Comment: @Gorgious Exactly :). No idea why these settings are missing in the Shader editor, seems like an oversight.

Comment: In case you want to try, this could be something for the papercut thread at blender developers. https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-ui-paper-cuts/2596

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your 3D Viewport Shading mode is set to "Material Preview", then these settings become relevant. For example, if you have a glass material and set the Blend mode to "Opaque", it is not transparent (just like in the render settings for Eevee).

*You can change Eevee settings there, without switching render engines.*
[image]

Comment: What shading mode do you mean? We have four viewport shading methods :)

Comment: Yeah, of course... I meant "Material Preview", I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ah thanks buddie. Now it makes sense :)

Comment: I guess the same counts for the eevee settings then?

Comment: Well, not exactly. In Eevee you don't have those specific Viewport Display settings. It just uses the regular settings that you've shown in the second picture.

Comment: It seems these *are* actual Eevee material settings. Just so you don't need to switch back and forth to adjust Material Preview :).

Comment: Indeed. It's the same operators in the same python file.